# Bootstrap Togglable tabs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

I want to use the [Togglable Tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) from Twitter's Bootstrap on a Rails app, but I can't make it work.

Here is my **app/views/pages/home.html.erb** :

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="dashboard_products">
  <li class="active"><a href="#owned_products"> 1 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#borrowed_products"> 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#given_products" > 3 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#requested_products"> 4 </a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="owned_products"> 1 </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="borrowed_products" > 2 </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="given_products" > 3 </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="requested_products" > 4 </div>
</div>
```

And here is my **app/assets/javascripts/pages.js.coffee** :

```cs
$ ->
  $('#dashboard_products a').click = (e) ->
    e.preventDefault() 
    $(this).tab('show')
```

And here my **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Where did I fail ?

Comment: Did you include bootstrap javascript to your assets ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are missing the `data-toggle` tag.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 well">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#home" data-target="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#profile" data-target="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="home">home tab content</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">profile tab content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZX3j/1/)

Comment: OK, this works !
But why twitter's bootstrap guide about the [tabs](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) don't show the `data-toggle = "tab"` in the methods paragraph ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have included bootstrap js ...and also check you include coffee script file after you include bootstrap js. and coffee script include must also be after your html. as dom must create the element before init tabs..

Comment: I added some info in my question. Is everything in order ?

Answer (score 0):

The example here

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

doesn't have a data-target attribute.

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="home">Home</a></li>
```

But when I add it

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
```

It all worked.